# How to format output neatly?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to format the values correctly just under the headers.
But i am unable to do so.

```
dl-Frequency :  Cell Id
    3088       :      6926
dl-Frequency :  Cell Id
    3088       :      6917
dl-Frequency :  Cell Id
    10712      :      6918
```

I used the prints in the code as below :

```
print('{:^10s} : {:^10s}'.format("dl-Frequency" , "Cell Id" ))
print('{:^15s} : {:^15s}'.format(result.group(4), result.group(3)))
```

Need your help.
How to calculate the left or right justification to put correct value in the `{:}`?

Comment: If you want a data frame, might want to consider using pandas, create a `pandas.DataFrame()` and just print it

Comment: Why did you use the number 10 in the first line and the number 15 in the second line? What happens if you use the same number in both lines?

Comment: @mkrieger1, it doesn't work even i put same number inside {}.

Comment: What numbers have you tried?

Comment: You should ask yourself: How many characters does the string `dl-Frequency` have? (Hint: it's more than 10) What does it mean to justify this string to 10 characters?

Comment: I am wondering looking at the down vote of this question. May i know the reason for that.

Comment: What part(s) of the [Format Specification Mini-Language](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language) don't you understand? Generally speaking, if you want print several variable-length items with something else following them neatly, you'll need to justify them all with a width that's big enough to accommodate the longest one. If you don't know that length in advance, your code will need to determine it at run time by finding the maximum length.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use `ljust` or `rjust` to ensure your text has the correct length?

For instance:

```py
print 'dl-Frequency :  Cell Id  '
print('{} : {}'.format(result.group(4).ljust(12), result.group(3)))
```

Comment: Hi @Leopold, Thanks for the answer but it is also not working as i expected.

Comment: Okay... Sorry to hear that. What's wrong with the output? Could you actually provide us with some input data to verify / play around ourselves?

Answer (score 0):

Use left alignment and right alignment to centre the names properly:

```
print('{:>10s} : {:<10s}'.format("dl-Frequency" , "Cell Id" ))
print('{:>10s} : {:<10s}'.format(result.group(4), result.group(3)))
```

You could, in theory, use a double format to alter the alignment length:

```
'{:<{}}'.format(len(name)).format(data)
```